# What is the difference between 0x0a and \n in for the ROWTERMINATOR parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between using 0x0a and \n for ROWTERMINATOR when importing data from an external source?

I tried to query data from a JSON file into rows and columns and I got different outcomes. Here is an image of the JSON file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUTlg.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
SELECT TOP 10*
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'taxi/raw/payment_type_array.json', 
        DATA_SOURCE='nyc_taxidata',
        FORMAT='CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION='1.0',
        FIELDTERMINATOR='0x0b',
        FIELDQUOTE='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
    )
    WITH
    (jsonDoc NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) AS payment_type
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSOn(jsonDoc)
    WITH(
        payment_type SMALLINT,
        payment_type_desc NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
    );
```

Here is the outcome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9hUK.png)

When I used '0x0a' as the FIELDTERMINATOR I got the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZmiJ.png)

Comment: `0x0a` is simply a hex representation of the ascii newline character, commonly stylised as `\n`.

Comment: I tried to query a JSON file using 0x0a and then \n as the ROWTERMINATOR. They gave me different results. I've added more information in the question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#specifying-n-as-a-row-terminator-for-bulk-import)

> #### Specifying `\n` as a Row Terminator for Bulk Import
>
> When you specify `\n` as a row terminator for bulk import, or implicitly use the default row terminator, bcp and the BULK INSERT statement expect a carriage return-line feed combination (CRLF) as the row terminator. If your source file uses a line feed character only (LF) as the row terminator - as is typical in files generated on Unix and Linux computers - use hexadecimal notation to specify the LF row terminator.

So if you are getting different results for `\n` and `0x0a` then you have some lines that are just using a line feed (LF) character, and some which are using carriage return (CR) followed by a line feed (LF) character (CRLF). This is a problem with the source data, in my opinion, as using inconsistent new line characters can (and does) cause problems.